# How to provide AJAX access to JSON file on server

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, nginx, cors

I know that if you have a JSON response you can provide CORS, or even wrap to be in a jSONP response.

But in this case, I have a JSON file sitting on the server, and I want multiple client applications to be able to AJAX to that file.

I'm getting the usual `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

Maybe this is an Nginx setting?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing#Simplified_example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Nginx

```
 if ($request_filename ~* ^.*?/([^/]*?)$) {
            set $filename $1;
    }

    if ($filename ~* ^.*?\.(json)$){
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
```